# moodle Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when selecting site administration

Tags: javascript, php, json, moodle

We just migrated a moodle site and for the most part everything is working well except the admin link site administration.  Once it is clicked, it will go on spinning for 3 minutes until it timeouts with a 500 error and an error message `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.  Here is the console output:

```
moodle/lib/ajax/getsiteadminbranch.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I disabled JS to get debug turned on but wasn't able to replicate the bug until I logged out and logged back in (JS turned on).

Replicating the steps above, I got a more verbose console log

[image: Chrome JS console with verbose moodle js notifications]

It seems to get hung up on

```
moodle-block_navigation: Loading navigation branch via AJAX: siteadministration
```

Here is the stack trace:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0    at JSON.parse >()
>   at Object.Y.namespace.parse (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:37340:18)
>   at BRANCH.ajaxProcessResponse (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?m/1477092989/block_navigation/navigation/navigation-debug.js:653:33)
>   at Y.Subscriber._notify (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26572:35)
>   at Y.Subscriber.notify (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26601:24)
>   at Y.CustomEvent._notify (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26264:17)
>   at Y.CustomEvent._procSubs (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26390:36)
>   at Y.CustomEvent.fireSimple (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26357:18)
>   at Y.CustomEvent._fire (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26339:29)
>   at IO.fire (https://foo-bar.io/moodle/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:27492:22)

The code worked on the old environment but obviously I am still missing something in the new one. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but your web site is returning HTML.  Perhaps an error message wrapped in HTML.  In future, you might want to actually copy and paste the error message - not an image of it.  Images of text have little value.

Comment: Your error message most likely means that a Javascript function is unable to parse the response of the AJAX call to `moodle/lib/ajax/getsiteadminbranch.php` because that script has failed.

Comment: To see the real error you will probably have to consult your server error log. That may be `/var/log/httpd/error.log` but will depend on what web server (eg Apache) and operating system you are running.

Comment: You should try the following and paste the response here: 1. Turn debugging on (if not done already). 2. Monitor this network request. 3. Check the response sent for this ajax request. That might give you more details on what actually happened on Moodle's end when that request for being made. If you can;t figure out what is wrong then you can post the response here.

Comment: @SandeepGill how do you monitor the network response?

Comment: @ChrisThroup here are the server logs
`[Sun Feb 05 08:15:46.646657 2017] [core:error] [pid 22720] [client 155.33.16.26:60344] Script timed out before returning headers: getsiteadminbranch.php, referer: https://foobar.edu/moodle/my/` This was the most relevant log record.

Comment: What I find interesting is this will always fail the first time but running a second time it will always work.

Comment: @user1941773 ..  you can monitor that request in google chrome Dev tools' network tab. Just click on the request and look at headers and response tabs

Answer (score 0):

I`ve solved the issue by uncommenting in my php.ini:
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

Source: http://php.net/always-populate-raw-post-data